# Asterisk: Make all calls go through extension

Tags: asterisk

I have a VoIP system implemented purely in Asterisk. Now, I have general users and privileged ones and a special extension, 555.
What I need: When general users call 555, they are "redirected" to extension 111 which may or may not transfer the call to 555. When a privileged user calls 555, the call goes through normally.
What is the best way of solving this? I'm thinking with contexts, but I want more opinions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use **GotoIF** condition in dialplan.

For check if user is "privileged" you can use some database access, for example via func_odbc.